# how to make inline-block 3-column layout

Tags: html, css

What's the best practice to make an inline-block layout consisting of 3 columns which two of them would be pushed to the right? How to achieve it if I want the colums' widths to be set to auto?

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="col1">left column needs to stay left
  </div>
  <div class="col2">middle goes to the right
  </div>
  <div class="col3">right please
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
  width: 800px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size:0;
  border: 1px dotted green;
}
.wrap div {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.col1 {
  background: red;
}
.col2 {
  background: blue;
}
.col3 {
  background: yellow;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/muriz/wrykjjs8/

Comment: In the future, please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a rather vaguely-worded reference to CodePen. Your post should stand alone from any other resource.

Comment: Which columns do you want to be auto? Define auto. Why do you specify you need them to be inline-block?

Comment: I didn't know I couldn't embed codepen here, I've just  edited a question

Comment: @David I can do it with floats but I would like to know how I can do the same with inline-block. I need all collumns to be auto (stretching to the width of the child element)

Comment: If you want the 2nd and 3rd column to the right of the container, then float might be easier (although you would have to change column order in source code). And having the columns automatically take the width their children dictate might get problematic, if that adds up to more than the containers width. (As an alternative to float, you might also want to look into flexbox.)

Answer (score 2):

```css
.col1,.col2,.col3{
 float:left;
 width:30%;
}
#col1{
 background-color:red;
 }
#col2{
 background-color:green;
 }
#col3{
 background-color:blue;
 }
```

```html
<div id="wrap">   
      <div id="col1" class="col1"> left column left column left column left column left             column left column left column
      </div>
   
      <div id="col2" class="col2"> 
        center column center column center column center column center column center column         center column center column
      </div>
   
      <div id="col3" class="col3">
          right columnright column right column right column right column right column               right column right column
      </div>
</div>
```

hope this helps you..